# Get adress origin and destination in mapbox gl directions

Tags: javascript, laravel, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using the `mapbox gl` directions from `mapbox`, which is used in the example of the mapbox documentation.

However, I can't get the values of address enter by the user .

I need the address selected by the user. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY TOKEN ACCESS';

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-79.4512, 43.6568],
        zoom: 13
    });

    map.addControl(
        new MapboxDirections({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
        }),
        'top-left'
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Docs for route event is here:
// https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#on`enter code here`
    directions.on('route', e => {
// routes is an array of route objects as documented here:
// https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#route-object:
      let routes = e.route
        routes.map(r => r.legs[0].steps[0].name)//get the origin
        tail=routes.map(r => r.legs[0].steps.length)//get length of instructions
        routes.map(r => r.legs[0].steps[tail-1].name)//get destination
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [mapbox-gl-directions plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions) provides [`getOrigin`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#getorigin) and [`getDestination`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md#getdestination) methods for retrieving the origin and destination of the current route, respectively.